# Сперва пришла ярость, затем отчаяние(,) и, наконец, трезвое рассуждение

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли указанная запятая?
Сперва пришла ярость, затем отчаяние(,) и, наконец, трезвое рассуждение. (Описывается состояние персонажа.)

Answer (score 3):

Я бы написала так:

*Сперва пришла ярость, затем отчаяние, **и наконец**, трезвое рассуждение.*

Это однородные члены, но по времени они дифференцированы с помощью наречий и вводного сочетания ***и наконец***.

Мы не можем не поставить указанную запятую, так как в этом случае соединим слова  *отчаяние* и  *трезвое рассуждение.*  Поэтому лучше отнести союз И к вводному слову.

Comment: Я бы тоже так написал, хотя у Розенталя нет аналогичного примера (есть "наконец и"), а в примере "Грамоты" и вовсе наоборот: http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_436 Где описано цельное сочетание "и наконец"?

Answer (score 0):

Это (скрытое) сложносочинённое предложение с пропущенным повторяющимся сказуемым в следующих частях. И есть явные ударения на каждую часть:
*Сперва пришла Ярость, затем (после этого события) [пришло] отчАяние, и, наконец (отдельно от остального), [пришло] трезвое рассуждЕние.*

Если не поставить эту запятую, то получается, что отчаяние и трезвое рассуждение пришли вместе. А вводное слово этому противоречит. Поэтому указанная запятая нужна.